# How do I write an if else statement in Reporting Services expression language?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I would like to write a Reporting Services `"Expression"` that basically behaves as the following (pseudo code)...

```
if ([Fields!StateProvinceId.Value] == 1)
{
   return "Ontario";
}
else if ([Fields!StateProvinceId.Value] == 2)
{
   return "Quebec";
}
else if ([Fields!StateProvinceId.Value] == 3)
{
   return "Manitoba";
}
// ...
// more cases same pattern
```

I don't see this type of logic do I have to nest a bunch of IIF?

```
=IIF(Fields!StateProvinceId.Value = 1, "Ontario", IIF(Fields!StateProvinceId.Value = 2, "Quebec", IFF(Fields!StateProvinceId.Value = 3, "Manitoba", "Unknown Province")))
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried a switch statement?

```
= Switch( Fields!StateProvinceId.value=1,"Ontario", Fields!StateProvinceId.value=2,"Quebec", Fields!StateProvinceId.value=3,"Manitoba")
```

See "decision functions" on this page for example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

Comment: Nope had not tried it.  Didn't see it.  I'll give it a shot thanks!