# SSRS Expression for IF, THEN ELSE

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-expression, shoretel

I am creating a field from tables with our shoretel phone system and i am intergrating reports via SSRS and i need some assisstance with an expression.

```
=if(Fields!ExitReason.Value 7,
then if (Fields!ExitReason.Value 1,
else if (Fields!ExitReason.Value 0,)))
```

Definition results should be:

```
=if(Fields!ExitReason.Value) = 7 then 1 else 0
```

I am try to get the field to  give me 7, 1 else 0. Any assistance would be great.

Thanks,
Arron

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551966/how-do-i-write-an-if-else-statement-in-reporting-services-expression-language

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
IIF(Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7, 1, 0)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

Comment: I have a field called ta_amount. if the value inside this filed is >100 then it's should be divided by 100 otherwise display "no pound".    but my expression gives me a error. 
=IIf((Fields!ta_amount.Value > 100), ([(Fields!ta_amount.Value)/100]), "No Pound")

Comment: I know this is old but the answer to @aselanuwan comment is found in this other SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283287/ssrs-how-to-make-iif-statement-ignore-invalid-values. In summary, IIF doesn't short-circuit, meaning it always evaluates both sides, regardless of the result.